# How to acquire call information from Teams call in a separate application in real time?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

We're trying to find a way to acquire information about a currently occurring call in Microsoft Teams - Phone number and direction of the call in particular - in a separate C# application.

In other words while a Teams call is active the separate application, running on the user's machine, should be able to capture and log the remote party and direction of the call.

There doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to do this in the Graph API that we've been able to find.

Comment: can you take a look at `call: updateMetadata` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-updatemetadata?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript

Comment: It also says `All the properties will be returned from an actual call.`