# MS Teams - tap into current phone call like a call center app and display additional information about the caller

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

We are moving from Skype for Business to Teams, and we need to port some CTE's we built for SFB. The main one we want going forward is a call center type experience. When a external call comes in, we look up a client's information based on the phone number and display it in the current call window. Even when the call hangs up, we leave the window there so they can enter some notes about the call which will be stored back into our own db.

How can we do this with Teams? After reading through Bots, Tabs, and Cards I can't see how these would work with in the context of an external phone call.

Is it possible to add a custom link in the "More Action" menu that we can launch a URL with call information on the querystring?

[image: Can we even just add our own menu item in the "More Action" menu?]

Do we have do it as an outside app using Microsoft Graph as in [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977475/how-to-acquire-call-information-from-teams-call-in-a-separate-application-in-rea)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported in Teams currently. We are working on this but We don't have ETA to share with you.

Comment: Can anyone update on this thread?